# Connect to MongoDB from .Net application with SSH

Tags: c#, mongodb, ssh

**I connected shh tunnel and ForwardedPortLocal but mongo client does not connect .
Here is my expection "Additional information: Unable to connect to server localhost:27000: Invalid credential for database 'db_name'.."**

var keyFile = new PrivateKeyFile(@"C:\Users\Desktop\mms_key.pem");
            var username = "mms-user";

```
        using (var client = new SshClient("dpmongo-0.sample.2121.mongodbdns.com",22, username, keyFile))
        {
            client.Connect();
            var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 27000, "localhost", 27000);
            client.AddForwardedPort(port);
            port.Start();

            var credentials = MongoCredential.CreateMongoCRCredential("db_name", "user_name", "password");

            MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings();
            settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost", 27000);
            settings.Credentials = new[] { credentials };

            var mongoEC2 = new MongoClient(settings);
            var server = mongoEC2.GetServer();

            var database = server.GetDatabase("db_name");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("tag");
            var query = Query.EQ("linkid", 2258021);
            var userFound = collection.FindOne(query);

            client.Disconnect();
        }
```

Comment: Take a closer look at your code - you're passing strings of 'db_name' and 'user_name' to the credential creation, not your variables.

Comment: Do you have another suggestion ?

Comment: Yes, pass in variables instead of strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
             string clientserver = "localhost";
             string _port = "27000";
             string mongo_username = "user_name";
             string mongo_password = "password";
             string databaseName = "db_name";
             var connectionString = "mongodb://"
                                                 + mongo_username + ":" + mongo_password + "@"
                                                 + clientserver + ":" + _port + "/"
                                                 + databaseName;
             var server = new MongoClient(connectionString).GetServer();   

            //I tried this and it gave the same error on c#. This information was linked to my experiment on MongoCfee tools.
```